# Genymotion is not flashing my zip

Tags: osx-mavericks, genymotion

I am trying to install Google Play in Genymotion. But when I drop the zip into the emulator, it saves the file in `/sd.../` instead of flashing it. How do I get the zip to flash?

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Macbook then uncheck Safari->Preferences->General : Open "safe" files after downloading .The issue seems that mac OS unzips the package if the option is checked and renders it unrecognisable by the Genymotion Emulator and hence does not get flashed but simply copied to the sdcard.

Comment: This is the exact answer I'm looking for! thanks mate!

Comment: I have Sierra, and I don't see this option under General.  Did it move somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to be aware of is that the name of your .zip file **cannot have spaces** in it, or it won't be recognized as Flashable.

Good: `my_flashable_filename_with_underscores.zip`

Bad: `my flashable filename with spaces.zip`

Answer (score 2):

If you are dropping and just get the `Files successfully copied to: /sdcard/Download/` message, it means your file is not being recognized as a flashable archive.  You should double-check that your `gapps-xx.zip` file is complete and not corrupted. Also, make sure you have the correct gapps for your platform (see http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#Downloads).

Comment: I was pulling my hair out over this one.  It seems since I renamed the GAPPS zip file to include spaces, the emulator no longer recognized it as a flashable archive.  Remove any spaces from the name of your zip.

Comment: This sort of explains the problem instead of answering the question.